# Why is this giving an "undefined" status

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to echo some JSON with PHP. My array which I am echoing is part static and part of it has multiple records in the array.

Code

```
$return_output = array();
$return_output['error'] = false;

while (($serverLog_line=fgets($fopen_serverLog))!==false) {
     $return_output[] = array(
         "line" => $serverLog_line,
     );
}

echo json_encode($return_output);
```

And the Jquery echoing it

```
$.getJSON("https://oasis-hosting.net/panel/handlers/server_functions/get.serverLog.php?service_id=22", 
function(result){
   var json = result;
   $.each(json, function(i, data) {
       $("#gameTerminal_content").append("" + data.line + "");
   })
});
```

Now, it does echo the results, however it will echo one result which says "undefined". Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/47d2fbef749b94585c78a79b207fa65f

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have your actual data list mixed in with the `error` element.

Change the structure such that the data is in its own array:

```
$return_output['error']     = false;
$return_output['data']     = array();
```

In the while:

```
$return_output['data'] = array(
    "line" => $serverLog_line,
);
```

In the JavaScript, iterate only over the data list not the error element:

```
var json = result.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

it is written on the command console, it writes:

"Can not read the property 'line' of null"

this means, $return_output returns null. I am not so good at php, but i think you return $return_output but you modify $return_output[].

these are looking like two different variables. this should be the reason.